# Can I change the place of preeposition in sentences below?

Tags: meaning

> I want from the heart him to make his valedictory before the public

Would this sentence mean the same if I use “from the heart” in the end of the sentence like

> I want him to  make his valedictory from the heart before the public

I though the meaning changed in the second sentence but I couldn’t be sure. Can you please correct me if I am wrong? In the frist sentence I tried to say I hope from the heart that he can speak easily before the people but in the second one I want him to make his speach from the hear.Are my thoughts correct ?

Comment: Yes, In the first, _from the heart_ modifies _want_, in the second, _make_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of the two sentences is, I think, pretty much correct:

> I want from the heart him to make his valedictory before the public

Here, "from the heart" would be interpreted as modifying "want", so that is, you are wanting from your heart for something to be true (for him to make his valedictory speech).

> I want him to make his valedictory from the heart before the public

Here, "from the heart" would be interpreted as modifying "make", that is you're expressing your desire that the speech that he makes would come from his heart.

I should note that the first sentence sounds a little awkward, mainly because there really should be a preposition between "want from the heart" and "him".  You could either say:

> I want from the heart **for** him to make his valedictory before the public.

or another way to phrase it would be:

> I want from the heart **that he** make his valedictory before the public.

(the "for" version is probably how people would phrase it more often).

Also, "want from the heart" isn't really wrong, but doesn't sound entirely natural to my ear.  I think most people would say either something like "wish from the heart" or "want with all my heart" (or "want wholeheartedly").  I think this is because "want" is not generally viewed as an action, but as more of a state-of-being, so it doesn't generally happen "from" somewhere, whereas "wish" is more of an action which can have an origin/direction to its action.

Comment: Thank you so much